# What’s the difference between the Room of Requirement and the Room of Hidden Things?

Tags: harry-potter

In *Harry Potter*, there is the Room of Requirement and the Room of Hidden Things; **are they both the same ?**

Comment: I'm like 99% sure I saw that exact question before. But can't seem to find it anymore.

Comment: The Room of Hidden Things is a form of the Room of Requirement. The Room of Requirement was quasi-sentient, because it transformed itself into whatever the witch or wizard needed it to be at that moment in time, although there were some limitations (like not being able to create food, as that is one of the five Principal Exceptions to Gamp's Law of Elemental Transfiguration). The Room of Requirement can turn into the Room of Hidden Things, if the wizard's or witch's purpose is to hide object(s). People like Albus Dumbledore, whose purpose was to use a bathroom, can see instead a bathroom.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Sort of.**

The Room of Hidden Things is merely one form that the Room of Requirement can take, for people who have a need for a place to hide something. When Harry goes to find it in *Deathly Hallows:*

> *I need the place where everything is hidden*, Harry begged of it inside his head, and the door materialized on their third run past.

He’s talking to the Room of Requirement, and when he enters it he finds that it’s taken the form of the Room of Hidden Things.

Comment: I'd say "yes and no", since it's only _one_ form it can take.

Comment: I agree with SQB, Room of Hidden Things != Room of Requirement but Room of Requirement can == Room of Hidden Things.

Comment: Maybe it's best to think of the ROHT as a subset of the ROR, like "cat" is a subset of "animal". The ROR can be potentially an infinite number of rooms, and the ROHT is one of the rooms it can be, popular because many students want to hide things.

Comment: @LeoKing Agreed, if one understands the mathematical concept of sets - which I think is fairly common, then this is very close image.

Answer (score 3):

The Room Of Requirement is known to be equipped for every need. When DA needed a place to practice TROR delivered. The room can take an infinite number of forms, whenever someone in Hogwarts needed to hide something TROR gave them The Room Of Hidden Things.

Comment: This is a good (right) answer, but do you have anything to add that isn't covered in the older answers?

Answer (score 0):

The Room of Hidden Things is located at the same place where the Room of Requirement is. Although, if the Room of Requirement is being use, the Room of Hidden Things cannot. Only one room may be used at a time. In order to access the Room of Hidden Things, the Room of Requirement must be emptied out, and then it becomes accessible.

Comment: -1 I think this answer is misleading even wrong. We are talking about only one room on the seventh floor and that is the Room of Requirement. The name comes from the fact, that it can change upon one's request, when the room is empty of people (or I'd rather say and other creatures). Room of Hidden Things is simple one of the forms the RoR can take (fairly often). Otherwise we could ask about Room of Dumbledore's Army etc., but that is wrong point of view. For lack of time and room, imagine boggart - it is still the same boggart even though it takes different forms.